# img scr showing invalid syntax in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
<img src="C:/Users/INTEX/Desktop/python_env/tulips.jpg"/>
```

output-File "", line 1
    
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: That's HTML, not Python.

Answer (score 10):

make sure you are on "Markdown" and not "Code" before you shift and enter in your Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 2):

Also happened to me once. Make sure you add this before writing

```
%%html
<img src = "xyz.png">
```

Answer (score 2):

You should switch to markdown use (<kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

You have to switch from code to markdown.

To switch from code to markdown, you can use the following keyboard shortcuts:

- `Esc + m` to switch to markdown
- `Shift + Enter` to run the cell

In your currently code cell where you include this image tag `<img src="C:/Users/INTEX/Desktop/python_env/tulips.jpg"/>`
switch to markdown, pressing  `Esc + m.` then press `Shift + Enter` to run the cell.